# Where should I set defaults on components with attributeBindings?

Tags: ember.js

I have a component `{{upload-image src=foo.bar}}`. When `foo.bar` is falsy I want to give it a different value. I setting the value in `init` like so:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['src'],
  tagName: 'img',

  init: function(){
    this.set('src', 'http://www.placecage.com/40/40');
    this._super();
    this.set('src', 'http://www.placecage.com/40/40');
  },

  click: function(){
    console.log(this.get('src'));
  }
});
```

However it doesn't work. The image gets rendered with the value I pass in, not the new one. When I click the image it does log the placecage image. Instead if I try to override it later on say `didInsertElement` it works as expected:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['src'],
  tagName: 'img',

  didInsertElement: function(){
    this.set('src', 'http://www.placecage.com/40/40');
  },

  click: function(){
    console.log(this.get('src'));
  }
});
```

It seems a bit silly to have it render out and only then be able to change the value causing (I presume) a re-render. What's the appropriate place to check if `src` is falsy and set it to a default and get the expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an open issue over on Github https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11637 where they seem to be saying that I shouldn't set the value using the two-way data binding this way.

I suppose I should make it read from a computed property instead and set my default from that.

Comment: Woah! I was using the SO review tool. I think an error occurred. I didn't leave that comment, it left it on my behalf. I may have clicked the wrong button, I guess? Looks fine to me.

Comment: @xdumaine fair enough. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Ember 1.13 you can do that in

```
attributeBindings: ['src:src'],

didInitAttrs() {
  this.set('src', <new value>);
}
```

Or you could do the falsy logic outside of the component and pass it in.

Comment: If you're passing in an object, it won't apply the set attribute value:

http://jsbin.com/jidisijici/1/edit

Comment: Ah, I believe you need to set the attributeBindings to this `attributeBindings: ['src:src']` if you're changing src at some point. I updated my answer above

Comment: Nah it works just fine with regular `src`, the colon's is for doing `element-attribute:component-attribute`, the problem is Ember doesn't react to attributes that is being set inside of any of the new `1.13` methods. There's a bug report that I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Okay. Just note that the bug is just it doesn't mutate attributes passed in coming from the controller but you can still set component-level attributes in it.

Answer (score 1):

I would create another property defined as follows:

```
effectiveSrc: function() {
    return this.get('src') || 'http://www.placecage.com/40/40';
}.property('src')
```

then use `effectiveSrc` in your logic and templates.

Another alternative is to give `src` a default:

```
src: 'http://www.placecage.com/40/40'
```

Then when calling your template, omit `src` if its value is falsy, something like

```
{{#if foo.bar}}
  {{upload-image src=foo.bar}}
{{else}}
  {{upload-image}}
{{/if}}
```

The following might also work, need to try it:

```
{{upload-image src=(if foo.bar foo.bar)}}
```

Comment: There's a couple of separate issues in relation to my code above. I can't seem to use `attributeBindings` with a calculated property. I did try to do `attributeBindings: ['src:effectiveSrc']` at one point, but couldn't get it working. Setting a default will always have it get overriden because I need to pass in the object that will get updated on completing the upload. I.e. `{{upload-image}}` sets the `src` value on upload, so the binding sets the data hence `attributeBindings`.

Comment: I think you got it wrong. Try `attributeBindings: ['effectiveSrc':'src']`. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

With ember 2.x (I've tested with 2.4.2, 2.4.3 and 2.5.0), I've achieved this functionality with the mentioned default by [torazaburro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo) :

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['src'],
  tagName: 'img',
  src: 'http://www.placecage.com/40/40',
  click() {
    console.log(this.get('src'));
  }
}
```

And the templates:

```
{{upload-image src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png"}}

{{upload-image}}
```

The [Twiddle to test it](https://ember-twiddle.com/53713dac2929544b856e6d6ef7fbe8b9?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.upload-image.hbs)